# Using volatile c-string with std::cout

Tags: c++, std, volatile, ostream

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
volatile char s[7] = "test";
int main() {
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
   std::printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

It prints "1" with std::cout and "test" with std::printf.  Why does it print "1" for the first case?!  My system is "Linux debian 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux", my C++ compiler is "g++ (GCC) 7.3.0".

If I remove "volatile" keyword then std::cout prints the expected "test".

Comment: I doubt using `volatile char*` with `%s` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

`printf` is variadic so takes any types of argument. `cout` is more strongly typed C++ thingie. A `char const volatile*` doesn't convert implicitly to `char const*`. But it converts to `bool`. Hence the 1.

Comment: Can this be considered a bug is standard library?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug. But it's certainly unexpected behavior. Just like trying to output a wide string via `cout`, or a narrow non-ASCII string via `wcout` in Windows.

Comment: I think standard library should have overload for volatile versions of `char *` and `void *`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what is the expected output for a string whose characters (which also means its length) can change while it's being printed? More in general, the common pattern in pretty much every library is to ignore `volatile` pointers; if the pointed object is "stable enough" to do something with it, the caller can confirm it by casting away the `volatile`.